# WPF can't use this object because its belongs to another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Im making a game in WPF and i created a new thread that neends to change the screen, this is the code:

```
Label cflabel = new Label();

Universal.mWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Universal.mWindow.MenuGrid.Children.Add(cflabel)));

//Universal.mWindow is the main window and it's a static object.
```

i've tried to use the Dispatcher in many different ways but the exception keeps poping, what am i missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the label in the same thread it is used:

```
Universal.mWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    Label cflabel = new Label();
    Universal.mWindow.MenuGrid.Children.Add(cflabel)));
}
```

This is because `Label` inherits from [`DispatcherObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can only be used on the thread it was created on.
From its documentation:

> Only the thread that the Dispatcher was created on may access the
>   DispatcherObject directly. To access a DispatcherObject from a thread
>   other than the thread the DispatcherObject was created on, call Invoke
>   or BeginInvoke on the Dispatcher the DispatcherObject is associated
>   with.

Comment: @Daniel great, glad I could help you!